# Django unique field on a subclass level?

Tags: python, django, orm

Let's say I have a base class Document that sublcasses into other document types.

Currently every instance of Document subclasses has a unique name, meaning that a Receipt instance with the name of 'foobar' cannot exist if a Statement instance has that same name.

```
class Document(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    date = models.DateField(default=None)
    place = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    project = models.ForeignKey('Project', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Receipt(Document):
    currency = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)

class Statement(Document):
    description = models.TextField()
```

How can I set up my models so that name is unique on subclass level, in other words, where I can have both a Statement and a Receipt with the name of 'foobar', but not two Receipts or Statements with the same name.

Comment: What if `Receipt` and `Statement` further have subclasses?

Comment: can you define `Document` as abstract?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem the same applies to all subclasses

Comment: @BearBrown I use that Document base class to filter through all the documents in the admin. Not sure if I can do that with abstract. Will try though.